# SSIS import a section of the source data

Tags: ssis

Sorry I am a SSIS beginner, hope you can help.

I have a source data table with a column call Country.

How can I choose to only import rows where Country = UK?

Many thanks!

Comment: Show us your code, and things you have tried..

Comment: Assume SSIS is not in the equation, how would you filter data from a table `WHERE Country = 'UK'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that your problem is that you are simply choosing a table. What you need to do is choose the **SQL Command** option instead and then write a **query** that does what you're expecting.

[image: Wrong]

[image: Right]